# Data submitted via a Userform not becoming active Hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I've created a user-form for a company to enter preferred  products, included is the product's website.  Currently when the user hits submit all the information is entered correctly, but the cell that contains the website is not a hyperlink to the website.  If I double click on the cell (as if to add text) and then exit the cell it turns the link into a hyperlink.

What VBA code do I need to turn data entered in a text-box and submitted via a user-form into a hyperlink in the cell on the sheet?

Here is the basic version of the code I have (Removed the other parts);

```
Private Sub ComboBoxDivision_Change()

Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber = ""
Me.ComboBoxSpecsName = ""
Select Case Me.ComboBoxDivision
    Case "DIVISION 02 - EXISTING CONDITIONS"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.RowSource = "D02_Number"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.RowSource = "D02_Name"

    Case "DIVISION 03 - CONCRETE"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.RowSource = "D03_Number"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.RowSource = "D03_Name"

    Case "DIVISION 04 - MASONRY"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.RowSource = "D04_Number"
    Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.RowSource = "D04_Name"    
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxSpecsNumber_Change()
Application.EnableEvents = False
  With ComboBoxSpecsNumber
    ComboBoxSpecsName.ListIndex = .ListIndex
  End With
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxSpecsName_Change()
Application.EnableEvents = False
  With ComboBoxSpecsName
    ComboBoxSpecsNumber.ListIndex = .ListIndex
  End With
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
If Me.ComboBoxDivision.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select a Division.", vbExclamation, "Product_Information_Form"
Me.ComboBoxDivision.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
If Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select a Specs Number or Name.", vbExclamation, "Product_Information_Form"
Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
If Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select a Specs Name or Name.", vbExclamation, "Product_Information_Form"
Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Worksheets("FormData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("FormData").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.ComboBoxDivision.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss")
End With

Select Case Me.ComboBoxDivision
Case "DIVISION 02 - EXISTING CONDITIONS"
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Div-02")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("a" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value

Case "DIVISION 03 - CONCRETE"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-03")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("a" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value

Case "DIVISION 04 - MASONRY"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-04")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("a" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsNumber.Value
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Me.ComboBoxSpecsName.Value
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value


End Select

Unload Product_Information_Form
Start_Form.Show

End Sub
```

P.S.  I've tried searching numerous times for a solution, but always get information on how to add a hyperlink to a user form, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: updating my answer since I notice you have multiple places where a link might be written out...

First add this utility Sub:

```
Sub AddLink(c As Range, txt As String)
    If Len(txt) > 0 Then
        c.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & txt & """)"
    Else
        c.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Then wherever you might write a link you can make use that sub:

e.g. change lines:

```
.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value

ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
```

to

```
AddLink .Offset(RowCount, 3), Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value 

AddLink ws.Range("c" & LastRow), Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value
```

respectively

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, but the code you offered currently results in an Compile error:   Invalid or unqualified reference.   The debugger highlights the first .Offset of the code you provided.      I inserted the code after the Dim RowCount As Long.  Is there a specific area I should insert the code?

Comment: Again Thanks for the fast response, however a different error occurred;  Run-time error '424'  Object required.  The debugger highlighted the AddLink . Offset(RowCount, 3).Value, Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value part of the code.  I added your code above the Private Sub SubmitButton_Click() section of my code.  I should note, I'm very new to VBA, have only been coding it the past few weeks.

Comment: My bad - I had not removed the `.Value` after  `.Offset(RowCount, 3)` - see my edit

Comment: THANK YOU, your code is working.  For the other section of code;  ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value   , what do I change it, since AddLink ws.Range("c" & LastRow) = Me.TextBox_Website_Link.Value  just results in a Compile error:  Argument not optional.

Comment: Added above - you need to pass two items to `AddLink` - a Range and a String

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, amazing how easy it is to over look a comma.  Your help was invaluable.

Comment: Is it possible to add the link another way, the =Hyperlink function has issues with http://www.google.com vs www.google.com.  Just updating the cell would be better as it allows Excel's built in Website Link software to register a website link listed in the cell.

Comment: `c.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=txt, TextToDisplay:=txt`

Comment: @TimWilliams maybe `c.Style.Name = "Hyperlink"` after adding it

Comment: Instead of c.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & txt & """)", but after posting that I noticed it still doesn't convert `www.google.com` into `http://www.google.com`;. I think Autocorrect does that, but I'm not sure it's accessible to VBA. You can just check to see of the link starts with "http://" and add it if it's missing.